# prisma orm update all records replace string with new string

Tags: node.js, orm, nestjs, prisma

| id | content |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | item1 |
| 2 | item2 |
| 3 | item3 |
| 4 | item4 |
| 5 | item5 |

A table likes above. How to use prisma orm replace content same string "item" to:

| id | content |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 5 |

I did't find some commands like "replace".

prisma.user.updateMany({
data:{
content:"just replace some string"
}
})

Thanks.

Comment: were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: @Noitidart No,I'm still waiting